# Sorting a string field doesn't sort correctly

Tags: sorting, solr, solr4

If I sort a **string** field called **code** I get the following resutls:

```
    {code:ABC-120GB}
    {code:ABC-120GBY}
    {code:ABC-120GY}
    {code:ABC-120G}
    {code:ABC-120GB}
    {code:ABC-120GBY}
    {code:ABC-120GY}
```

These are the configuration for the mentioned field from the `schema.xml` file:

```
<fields
    <field name="code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/> 
</fields>

<types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
</types>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the first level sort on the `code_length` is working. Does the sort on `code` work if it's the only sort specified? My suspicion is that you would see the same issues with the sort on the `code` field if it were the only field you were using for sort.

It seems quite likely that the problem you're seeing is caused by variations in the data we can't see because you haven't included the real data. It would be interesting to see if you can recreate this problem with the data you actually posted, or other non-sensitive values. For one, I would suspect invisible variations in the character encoding. If that's the case, you could try modifying the `code` field to be a single-token text-based field rather than an unmodified string field. Then, you have the choice of various filters to add to that fieldType that could normalize encoding variations. A good filter to consider is the [**ICU Folding Filter**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ICUFoldingFilter) which manages a lot of normalization and can be added to your `fieldType` definition with this line:

```
<filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
```

You could consider this definition for a `fieldType` called "exact" that might work for you. By "tokenizing" the value into one large token, it preserves the exact-match searching you have now with the `code` field having `type="string"`, and it will make Solr happy by only having one token on a sort field as well.

```
  <fieldType name="exact" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
         input string is preserved as a single token
      -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then you'd change your `code` field definition to:

```
<field name="code" type="exact" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Of course, this is somewhat speculative since I can't know what the data I'm not seeing might show me, and the ICU Folding Filter cannot adjust for everything that might be causing your trouble. But I hope this helps.

- *Note: because sorting doesn't work on multiValued fields, I recommend explicitly specifying `multiValued="false"` for any fields you plan to use for sorting. It will be less ambiguous.*

Comment: Thanks, the `multiValued="false"` modification nailed it

Comment: After all that speculation it was the footnote that answered the question. At least it's working now.

Comment: I hope someone will find it useful too.

Comment: Well, the pattern I outlined is my baseline for creating alphabetic sort fields for arbitrary human-readable metadata. The only thing I might add to it is stripping of punctuation I don't want to sort by (depending on context). I'm not sure I explained the normalization well. An example is `é` which in UTF-8 can be encoded as an old-school extended ASCII single byte character, or a new-format `e + diacritic` wide character. Without normalization, these are not the same character. And yet, for most values that are not human language data this is unlikely to be an issue.